# How to make a master page inherit only one feature from another master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have 2 masterpages called User.Master and Admin.Master. Admin.Master as the name suggests is for administrator and User.Master is for users. The User.Master has Login and Sign-Out  functionality and a sidebar of its own. The Admin.Master has a sidebar of its own. Now I want the Admin.Master to inherit Login and Sign-Out functionality but not the User.Master's sidebar. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a third master page, `LogInOut.master`, which includes the login and logout stuff, and from which you then derive both `User.master` and `Admin.master`, providing each with their specific sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 master pages to do that.

1) Primary Master - Login and Sign-out

2) User Master - Inherits Primary Master | User Side Bar

3) Admin Master - Inherits Primary Master | Admin Side Bar

Edit: ^^ Beat me!

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three ways to do this fairly simply, of which I prefer the first approach:

1. Just create a user control for the log in/out functionality, and include the same user control on both master pages (user/admin).
2. Skip the double master pages approach completely. Instead have just one master page with a user control for the log in/out functionality, and a user control each for the side bars. Which user control is loaded (e.g. into a placeholder on the masterpage) is controlled in the master page's code behind, where you can check for session details on login etc.
3. As several others have suggested, use 3 master pages that nest each other.

Comment: its a good plan but here is the catch, i'm manually implementing the login functionality with sessions.

Comment: @user: That shouldn't pose a problem - you should be able to encapsulate any log in/out code in your user control, and any check code in the master page, regardless of your storage and retrieval system.